# Changing from two lense into one view. Unity GoogleVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

Im developing a VR mobile app by implement the GoogleVR package.
So im planning to make another version that also use and have all what GoogleVR have. Except for the view.

So, instead of let it have two different view, I want to make it to become only one view.

Really need help.
Thank you in advance.